# Integrating Storyboards and XIB's

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xib, uistoryboard

Im primarily using Storyboards for my application however I want to make a xib for a viewcontroller that is already in storyboard and replace the content inside the view controller with the stuff in the xib. How would i present the xib and still use storyboard?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you would want to do this, but you do what you always do with view controllers whose views are created in xibs, use initWitNibName:bundle:, to instantiate the controller, then put it on screen however you want, with a push or presentViewController. The fact that you're using a storyboard is irrelevant to how you instantiate and show the view controller.